# Inject properties into FlatFileItemWriter in Spring batch

Tags: java, properties, spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet, spring-batch-excel

I need to generate a file called: `NEW_NAME_YYYY-MM-DD` where `YYYY-MM-DD` is the current Date. Everything works fine except for when my batch tries to get the propertie `tmp.dir` it finds nothing and calls the directory `null` instead. This is the Writer class I am working with :

```
public class MyFileWriter extends FlatFileItemWriter {

   @Value("${tmp.dir}")
   private String tempDir;

   public MyFileWriter(){
      super();
      setResource();
   }

   public void setResource() {
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
      String stringDate = sdf.format(new Date());
      String myPath = tempDir + "/NEW_NAME_" + stringDate + ".csv";
      Resource outputFile = new FileSystemResource(myPath);
      this.setResource(outputFile);
   }

}
```

and this is the bean definition placed in `applicationContext.xml` along with the property-placeholder for the properties file:

```
<bean id="csvWriter" class="org.conters.writer.MyFileWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
            <property name="delimiter" value=";" />
            <property name="fieldExtractor">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                    <property name="names" value="ad,customer,total" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="encoding" value="${csv.encoding}" />
</bean>
```

Any idea on why the propertie isn't injected??? and as for the properties file called `batch.properties` in my case **it is well declared in the applicationcontext**.

Comment: Is `tmp.dir` defined in your `batch.properties` file or are your trying to inject the Java System property `java.io.tmpdir`? I see you use `temporaryDir` in the `setResource` method while the variable is called `tempDir`. Is that intended or it's a typo? Since you defined your bean in XML config, what about adding a setter for `tempDir` in your `MyFileWriter` class and add `<property name="tempDir" value="${tmp.dir}" />` in your XML? IMO this is more consistent than mixing both styles of configuration (annotations and XML).